# C++ template overloading query

Tags: c++

I have seen an interesting question here: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-466357.html

Here is the report:

```
template<class T, class C> void foo(T op1, C op2) {}; //line 1
template<class C, class T> void foo(C op1, T op2) {}; //line 2
template<class T, class C> void foo(C op1, T op2) {}; //line 3
```

Q> When the above code is compiled, which line will give an error, and why.

Comment: The first two are exactly the same.

Comment: Did you read the answers there?

Comment: @p.campbell, if you read original post, you should not have posted this comments here. The original post doesn't provide a credible answer for this question. I don't know why this question should be closed!

Comment: @Vence: Because it was answered by the second comment in that link. If you don't feel that this is credible, that's too bad, but that is more or less the answer.

Comment: @Nicol, so you also think both line 2 and line 3 are wrong?

Comment: I don't see an answer there either (1 and 3 can coexist, but then a call can't be resolved only by argument type deduction). And the function can't be called if both arguments are the same type. - Anyway, the answer may be compiler-dependent. People saying that templates never give errors until instantiated are VC++ users? For gcc users: http://ideone.com/Mozr2